# new WPMS site not working / Q setting up new site/subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain, domain-mapping, troubleshooting

I have followed all the instructions and read several articles verifying the config for WPMS was done correctly.   My root site works fine, but when trying to go to the dashboard (or the direct URL) of my newly created site/subdomain (from MySites->NetworkAdmin->Sites, then dashboard link), "http://www.technology.americanthought.org/wp-admin/" I get "Site Not Found page" (and the wp-admin directory isn't located under the new site/subdomain directory ./technology.americanthought.org )

In looking within the new subdomain site directory, I only see 3 files :

-rw-r--r-- 1 tjobson pg8931404 777 Apr 12 18:04 quickstart.html

-rw-r--r-- 1 tjobson adm         0 Apr 12 18:04 favicon.gif

-rw-r--r-- 1 tjobson adm         0 Apr 12 18:04 favicon.ico

I would assume that for a new "stub" site, I'd be able to use the dashboard to go in and customize, import, whatever.. ?

Q?>  ? Do I need to first copy over all the WP folders to create this new site, where I assumed since everything is setup as network shared themes/plugins.. I wouldn't need to ??

If this is the case that I do need to copy over site folders/files from another (the root domain site config), it seems that this should have been an install/config option, or some default stub's be created ?
What's more concerning is that in NO documentation.. and I've read ~10 admin guides for this.. NO WHERE does it say / explain the new site directory structure, NOR a process required to setup/configure the new site (what to copy if so.. etc.).

I'm now questioning whether I need some wildcard DNS entry.. or ?? (but would assume my config is broken and needs to be installed within the subdomain directory ?(Y/N)

Neither dreamhost, other boards/past-QA.. nor my paid-for theme developers have any answers.

Let me know, your assistance is greatly appreciated !
Todd

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new directory for your subdomain. Both your main URL (www.americanthought.org) and your subdomain URL (www.technology.americanthought.org) should point to the same directory. Multisite will serve the sites from the same set of WordPress files.

(I took a quick peek, and it appears that you've got your subdomain's DNS entry pointing at an IP address, which is good. Your main site has a different IP address, but I assume that's because you're using CloudFlare.)

You *will* need to set up your `.htaccess` file correctly. [According to the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), you *probably* want the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

...but I can't say with 100% certainty because I don't know what your site's setup looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.    I followed all the .htaccess and wp-config.php config needs and verified w the codes.   However, It sounds like I should have a rootdomain (original site base installation) wp-content/uploads/sites folder as the WP Codex suggests after any Multisite installation ?? (yes?), which I don't.

Comment: Yes, but this should have been automatically created when you first uploaded a file to a sub-site (or you might have seen an error about the `wp-content/uploads` directory not being writable).